# Perl: find the team of a player. Is there a more elegant way?

Tags: perl, config

i have several teams in a file teams.txt looking like:

```
team1 = {bob marc steve}
team2 = {john maria}
```

The file formatting I can change according to my taste.

Now I need to find out, to which team a player, say bob, belongs.
Up to now I'm using `open file -> while -> match pattern` for that.

I wonder if i can reformat the file teams.txt and use Config::General or
any other preconceived tool from cpan.

Pls I will enjoy very much new ideas!
(using perl 5)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a real word task and the files are big I would use SQLite and some basic SQL query to get this information.

Nasty, but simple:

```
my $player = 'john';
#return only the team names
my @found  = `grep -w $player file1 file2 | cut -f1 -d"="`;
chomp(@found);
if (@found){
  print "We found $player in teams: ".join(',',@found)."\n";
}
```